# Declaration of HelloController::display() should be compatible with JControllerLegacy::display($cachable = false, $urlparams = Array)

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to call display function here is my controller.php code
[Controller.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du8gf.jpg)

What change should I make to make this code working? Please help me with errors.

Comment: Please explain in brief.. and what errors you got

Comment: There is my controller code in img comtroller.php Display function in this is now roking

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the display function as below

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
```